# Tabulator: Guidance on implementing custom sort/paginate/filter/edit behavior

Tags: vue.js, electron, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator in a Vue.js powered Electron desktop app. My app can query quite large datastores and displays the results in a Tabulator table.

What I want to do is basically the same as the ajax module, but instead of making AJAX calls to fetch new data I want to call a specific API.

I'm starting with sorting. When clicking the header to sort, I want to call the custom api with the sort parameters, then return a sorted slice of data. There doesn't seem to be a 'native' way to do this in the Tabulator sort module api.

Same deal with pagination -- display only ~100 results, if they paginate to the next page, I make an API call.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Can/should I build my own module (drafted from the ajax module), or do `sort` and `paginate` integrate with the ajax module directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ***ajaxRequestFunc*** callback to replace the existing ajax request mechanic with your own logic. Full details for this can be found in the [Loading Data, Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/data#ajax-promise)

The example below shows a new function ***queryRealm*** being used to replace the built in ajax functionality.

The function will be passed a url and config and params objects, that will contain sorting, filtering and pagination data, and should return a promise that resolves with an array of table data

```
function queryRealm(url, config, params){
    //url - the url of the request
    //config - the ajaxConfig object
    //params - the ajaxParams object

    //return promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //do some async data retrieval then pass the array of row data back into Tabulator
        resolve(data);

        //if there is an error call this function and pass the error message or object into it
        reject();
    });
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxRequestFunc:queryRealm,
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I did. Good answer!